# Tinymce editor is not loading in testcafe automation

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, tinymce, testcafe

When I try to load a page which contains tinymce editor, testcafe is not able to load it.

```
import { screen, within } from "@testing-library/testcafe";
import { Selector } from "testcafe";

fixture`test`
  .page('https://example.com')

test('create element', async t => {
  await t.wait(5000);
  const text1 = Selector(".MuiBox-root.css-ircbac > button");
  await t.wait(5000);
  await t
    .click(text1)
    .wait(8000)
  
    await t.wait(15000);

});
```

The above page contains a editor and the textbox. The textbox is loading but editor is not loading

Comment: You put in the wrong example page, there are no TinyMCE editors. Please create a simple reproducible sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The `tinymce` editor is not loading while loading `testcafe` scripts. It's throwing **internal server error** for `tinymce` network call. Run the script by adding below command at the end
`--experimental-proxyless`
eg: `testcafe test/e2e/src/*/example.js --experimental-proxyless`